# How to create multiple image grid?

Tags: java, android, image, kotlin

I need to make a grid. Images will be located there, and they must adapt to the size of the grid.
I tried to do this with a StaggeredGridLayoutManager, but I need to stick it in recyclerview.

It should be something like this:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsITl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexboxlayout manager this will arrange images an grid with size adjustment order

```
 val layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(activity)
 layoutManager.flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
 layoutManager.justifyContent = JustifyContent.FLEX_START
 layoutManager.flexWrap = FlexWrap.WRAP
industryChannelBinding.manageChannelRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```

You have to add  flexbox dependency

```
 implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Recyclerview you can set the layoutManager of the Recyclerview either in the layout XML file, or in your Java code when you set up your views. To get something like that in the image you uploaded, I would suggest using [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView) in the layout for your Recyclerview items.

To set it in XML, you could do something like

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:spanCount="3"/>
```

where `spanCount` is the number of columns you want.

To do the same thing in code, you could do something like

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 3)
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager)
```